# How can I use StringBody to upload a file with HttpMime?

Tags: java, groovy, apache-commons

```
def params = new MultipartEntity();

params.addPart("name", new StringBody(fileName))
params.addPart("file", new StringBody(fileContent))
post.setEntity(params)

def response = httpclient.execute(post)
```

This code does not work.

```
def fileContent = new FileBody(new File(fileName))
def params = new MultipartEntity();

params.addPart("name", new StringBody(fileName))
params.addPart("file", fileContent)
post.setEntity(params)
```

This code does.

It breaks because I get a 400 Bad Request from the Tomcat server I am POSTing to. I do not know why it says this, it is an application outside of my control.

I do not want to write temporary files to the hard drive. I am not clear how I can avoid this now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use name as `body` in place of `file` as:

```
  params.addPart("body", new StringBody(fileContent));
```